# What to do when two tables need to be joined on text columns?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two tables, a linked table called AllData and normal table called MIUOffset. They both have a text column called MIUType. I need to join the two tables on MIUType and while the join of `Inner Join MIUOffset on AllData.MIUType = MIUOffset.MIUType` works, eventually, it is intolerably slow.

Is there any way to join tables on string fields and have it work anywhere near as quickly as joining on numeric fields?

My fallback plan is to modify the linked table in its database to have an integer field to act as a numeric key for the MIUType data, but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it.

What I'm trying to do ultimately, is add/subtract columns as part of a where statement and the MIUOffset table has the offset for each unique MIUType. The resultant equation is something like `AllData.[0] + MIUOffset.Offset < -95`.

So aside from adding a numerical key equivalent to the MIUType data in the core data structure, or restructuring the code to loop through each MIUType and then add up the results at the end, is there any way to do this?

I'd prefer the solution to be strictly in the sql but this is all being done in VBA so there are other options if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: When joining a linked table, MS-Access must transfer all rows to the local machine. When the table is large, it can take a lot of time as you are experiencing. Is it possible to migrate the local table onto the DB server?

Comment: Does this field doesn't get modified frequently? If not, adding an index could enhance search and joining. But first, I recommend you check if @Mat'sMug's answer can be implemented. the more values in `MIUType` are repeated, you should consider his solution.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments. Missing indexes on the `MIUType` fields in both tables and joining local with linked tables are probably a bigger problem than the field being text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is there any way to join tables on string fields and have it work anywhere near as quickly as joining on numeric fields?*

You don't. Instead, you *normalize* your tables. Joining on a numeric field is *by definition* much faster than joining on a string field.

How many times are values in `MIUType` repeated in both columns?

> *My fallback plan is to modify the linked table in its database to have an integer field to act as a numeric key for the MIUType data, but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it.*

That's not a "fallback plan", it should have been the proper design in the first place. I'm not sure why you would want to *avoid it*.

Make a separate table to store all the possible values *once*, and map each one to a numeric ID (an *autonumber* primary key field will do / `identity` if the linked source is on SQL Server).

Then add a `MIUTypeId` column to your tables, and run an update to link the values by their numeric ID. Then remove the redundant `MIUType` string column, and from now you join on `MIUTypeId` to get the associated string value. If that breaks 20 reports and 15 views, then don't drop the column, but fix the 20 reports and 15 views to use the new field, and then when the dependencies on the string column are all gone, remove it.

Comment: It wasn't there because it only just now came up that I needed it, I'm just now having the situation arise. Guess there isn't a palitable way around it so I'll just have to add in the column, a seperate table, and an event or something to make sure the table gets updated if a new MIUType gets added into the database. Thanks.